log ratio transformation on data and GLM testing on 4-way olfactometry results
I recently completed an experiment looking at 40 individual aphids movement over 20 minutes inside a 4-arm olfactometer with 3 controls (no scent, uninfected aphids, agar) and aphids infected with the fungus B. Bassiana. I logged how long each aphid spent in each zone and how many times they were visited.
for the purpose of the analysis, the center zone, zone 5, was removed prior to calculating the proportion of time spent in each of the odour zones
Between each test the odour sources were rotated clockwise to new zones to remove directional bias. I converted the times into seconds. T_min = time in minutes, T_sec = time in seconds, Trial = which aphid was being tested T_ vis = times visited, source is the type of odour, zone is where each odour was connected to the olfactometer, T_prop = proportion of time spent, constant = proportion plus a constant of 0.001.
I'd like to know how I would use the  compositions package to perform a log ratio transformation on the constant column. I'd then like to know how to use this result in a GLM test to compare the time spent near each odour source with each other
I'm using R and I have provided the dput below.
Thank you for any help!
structure(list(Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L), Zone = c("Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", 
"Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", 
"Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", 
"Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", 
"Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", 
"Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", 
"Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", 
"Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", 
"Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", 
"Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", 
"Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", 
"Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", 
"Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", 
"Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", 
"Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", 
"Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", 
"Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", 
"Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", 
"Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", 
"Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", 
"Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", 
"Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", 
"Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", "Zone 4", "Zone 1", "Zone 2", 
"Zone 3", "Zone 4"), Source = c("uninfected", "infected", "agar", 
"blank", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", "agar", "agar", "blank", 
"uninfected", "infected", "infected", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", 
"uninfected", "infected", "agar", "blank", "blank", "uninfected", 
"infected", "agar", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", 
"infected", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", "uninfected", "infected", 
"agar", "blank", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", "agar", "agar", 
"blank", "uninfected", "infected", "infected", "agar", "blank", 
"uninfected", "uninfected", "infected", "agar", "blank", "blank", 
"uninfected", "infected", "agar", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", 
"infected", "infected", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", "uninfected", 
"infected", "agar", "blank", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", 
"agar", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", "infected", 
"agar", "blank", "uninfected", "uninfected", "infected", "agar", 
"blank", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", "agar", "agar", "blank", 
"uninfected", "infected", "infected", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", 
"uninfected", "infected", "agar", "blank", "blank", "uninfected", 
"infected", "agar", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", 
"infected", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", "uninfected", "infected", 
"agar", "blank", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", "agar", "agar", 
"blank", "uninfected", "infected", "infected", "agar", "blank", 
"uninfected", "uninfected", "infected", "agar", "blank", "blank", 
"uninfected", "infected", "agar", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", 
"infected", "infected", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", "uninfected", 
"infected", "agar", "blank", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", 
"agar", "agar", "blank", "uninfected", "infected", "infected", 
"agar", "blank", "uninfected"), T_min = c("11:08", "08:07", "00:00", 
"00:00", "00:00", "09:44", "07:03", "01:32", "00:51", "03:03", 
"09:03", "01:13", "02:42", "00:41", "04:39", "09:18", "00:00", 
"18:37", "00:00", "00:00", "04:10", "12:46", "00:34", "01:09", 
"00:00", "03:41", "08:20", "06:09", "05:37", "03:41", "01:05", 
"07:39", "07:30", "02:08", "01:26", "07:30", "09:28", "07:14", 
"00:53", "00:00", "04:41", "01:17", "07:01", "03:49", "04:42", 
"00:37", "03:04", "06:55", "06:45", "03:21", "01:51", "05:43", 
"03:21", "07:06", "06:27", "00:00", "00:12", "03:56", "03:23", 
"05:46", "00:21", "01:52", "00:00", "12:49", "09:31", "00:00", 
"01:50", "04:22", "08:53", "07:32", "00:00", "01:13", "00:00", 
"02:04", "09:27", "07:45", "00:00", "00:00", "04:37", "07:37", 
"518.5380001", "200.062", "00:00", "336.8510001", "138.598", 
"725.7896647", "120.678", "126.1030002", "00:00", "100.1020002", 
"898.7535079", "101.5700002", "36.921", "00:00", "107.2359998", 
"548.3749998", "598.1629999", "00:00", "14.60599995", "458.263", 
"00:00", "601.4129617", "342.6340001", "00:00", "00:00", "204.6829998", 
"459.7729383", "00:00", "00:00", "40.14700007", "267.1610003", 
"520.207", "713.6819999", "00:00", "00:00", "209.1398592", "511.0800002", 
"436.1260002", "00:00", "00:00", "00:46", "00:00", "09:19", "02:26", 
"07:10", "00:00", "02:41", "08:04", "10:55", "03:42", "00:00", 
"03:08", "00:00", "07:10", "06:04", "01:57", "00:00", "03:11", 
"11:19", "02:58", "03:30", "00:00", "00:00", "10:31", "15:01", 
"01:27", "00:00", "02:59", "01:08", "10:53", "00:00", "00:26", 
"00:00", "00:00", "14:15", "03:07", "03:47", "05:16", "01:57", 
"08:26"), T_sec = c(668L, 487L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 584L, 423L, 92L, 
51L, 183L, 543L, 73L, 162L, 41L, 279L, 558L, 0L, 1117L, 0L, 0L, 
250L, 766L, 34L, 69L, 0L, 221L, 500L, 369L, 337L, 221L, 65L, 
459L, 450L, 128L, 86L, 450L, 568L, 434L, 53L, 0L, 281L, 77L, 
421L, 229L, 282L, 37L, 184L, 415L, 405L, 201L, 111L, 343L, 201L, 
426L, 387L, 0L, 12L, 236L, 203L, 346L, 21L, 112L, 0L, 769L, 571L, 
0L, 110L, 262L, 533L, 452L, 0L, 73L, 0L, 124L, 567L, 465L, 0L, 
0L, 277L, 457L, 518L, 200L, 0L, 336L, 138L, 725L, 120L, 126L, 
0L, 100L, 898L, 101L, 36L, 0L, 107L, 548L, 598L, 0L, 14L, 458L, 
0L, 601L, 342L, 0L, 0L, 204L, 459L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 267L, 520L, 
713L, 0L, 0L, 209L, 511L, 436L, 0L, 0L, 46L, 0L, 559L, 146L, 
430L, 0L, 161L, 484L, 655L, 222L, 0L, 188L, 0L, 430L, 364L, 117L, 
0L, 191L, 679L, 178L, 210L, 0L, 0L, 631L, 901L, 87L, 0L, 179L, 
68L, 653L, 0L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 855L, 187L, 227L, 316L, 117L, 506L
), T_vis = c(3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 4L), T_prop = c(0.578856153, 0.422010399, 0, 0, 0, 
0.531876138, 0.385245902, 0.083788707, 0.060141509, 0.215801887, 
0.640330189, 0.086084906, 0.156219865, 0.039537126, 0.269045323, 
0.538090646, 0, 1.000896057, 0, 0, 0.223813787, 0.685765443, 
0.030438675, 0.061772605, 0, 0.202938476, 0.459136823, 0.338842975, 
0.311748381, 0.204440333, 0.06012951, 0.424606846, 0.404676259, 
0.115107914, 0.077338129, 0.404676259, 0.541984733, 0.414122137, 
0.050572519, 0, 0.279324056, 0.076540755, 0.418489066, 0.227634195, 
0.308533917, 0.0404814, 0.20131291, 0.45404814, 0.384250474, 
0.190702087, 0.105313093, 0.325426945, 0.2, 0.423880597, 0.385074627, 
0, 0.01509434, 0.296855346, 0.255345912, 0.435220126, 0.023359288, 
0.12458287, 0, 0.855394883, 0.606801275, 0, 0.116896918, 0.278427205, 
0.504734848, 0.428030303, 0, 0.069128788, 0, 0.109637489, 0.50132626, 
0.411140584, 0, 0, 0.378415301, 0.62431694, 0.491461101, 0.189753321, 
0, 0.318785579, 0.12477396, 0.655515371, 0.108499096, 0.113924051, 
0, 0.092850511, 0.833797586, 0.093779016, 0.057142857, 0, 0.16984127, 
0.86984127, 0.56097561, 0, 0.013133208, 0.429643527, 0, 0.64762931, 
0.368534483, 0, 0, 0.307692308, 0.692307692, 0, 0, 0.048367594, 
0.322853688, 0.628778718, 0.773318872, 0, 0, 0.226681128, 0.462862319, 
0.394927536, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0.75951087, 0.198369565, 0.416666667, 
0, 0.156007752, 0.468992248, 0.619678335, 0.210028382, 0, 0.177861873, 
0, 0.478841871, 0.405345212, 0.130289532, 0, 0.182425979, 0.64851958, 
0.170009551, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.751190476, 0.772727273, 0.074614065, 
0, 0.153516295, 0.091275168, 0.876510067, 0, 0.034899329, 0, 
0, 0.82768635, 0.181026137, 0.195017182, 0.271477663, 0.100515464, 
0.434707904), constant = c(0.579856153, 0.423010399, 0.001, 0.001, 
0.001, 0.532876138, 0.386245902, 0.084788707, 0.061141509, 0.216801887, 
0.641330189, 0.087084906, 0.157219865, 0.040537126, 0.270045323, 
0.539090646, 0.001, 1.001896057, 0.001, 0.001, 0.224813787, 0.686765443, 
0.031438675, 0.062772605, 0.001, 0.203938476, 0.460136823, 0.339842975, 
0.312748381, 0.205440333, 0.06112951, 0.425606846, 0.405676259, 
0.116107914, 0.078338129, 0.405676259, 0.542984733, 0.415122137, 
0.051572519, 0.001, 0.280324056, 0.077540755, 0.419489066, 0.228634195, 
0.309533917, 0.0414814, 0.20231291, 0.45504814, 0.385250474, 
0.191702087, 0.106313093, 0.326426945, 0.201, 0.424880597, 0.386074627, 
0.001, 0.01609434, 0.297855346, 0.256345912, 0.436220126, 0.024359288, 
0.12558287, 0.001, 0.856394883, 0.607801275, 0.001, 0.117896918, 
0.279427205, 0.505734848, 0.429030303, 0.001, 0.070128788, 0.001, 
0.110637489, 0.50232626, 0.412140584, 0.001, 0.001, 0.379415301, 
0.62531694, 0.492461101, 0.190753321, 0.001, 0.319785579, 0.12577396, 
0.656515371, 0.109499096, 0.114924051, 0.001, 0.093850511, 0.834797586, 
0.094779016, 0.058142857, 0.001, 0.17084127, 0.87084127, 0.56197561, 
0.001, 0.014133208, 0.430643527, 0.001, 0.64862931, 0.369534483, 
0.001, 0.001, 0.308692308, 0.693307692, 0.001, 0.001, 0.049367594, 
0.323853688, 0.629778718, 0.774318872, 0.001, 0.001, 0.227681128, 
0.463862319, 0.395927536, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0635, 0.001, 0.76051087, 
0.199369565, 0.417666667, 0.001, 0.157007752, 0.469992248, 0.620678335, 
0.211028382, 0.001, 0.178861873, 0.001, 0.479841871, 0.406345212, 
0.131289532, 0.001, 0.183425979, 0.64951958, 0.171009551, 0.251, 
0.001, 0.001, 0.752190476, 0.773727273, 0.075614065, 0.001, 0.154516295, 
0.092275168, 0.877510067, 0.001, 0.035899329, 0.001, 0.001, 0.82868635, 
0.182026137, 0.196017182, 0.272477663, 0.101515464, 0.435707904
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -160L))


I don't know the {conditions} package. Can you provide a link? Keep in mind that questions about how to use procedure X in package Y are off-topic on Cross Validated.

That's my fault, the package is actually called {compositions}, from here: "http://www.stat.boogaart.de/compositions/". I mainly ask about this package as reading through olfactometry papers, it's best to logratio transform the data before fitting a GLM mixed model.
